# Please reverse the migration of this question to ELL

Tags: discussion

I'm reliably informed that ELU can do nothing at this point, and that the migration must be rejected here by the powers that be.  This was my question on ELU's meta:

The [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82366/can-childs-ever-be-the-plural-of-child) is

Can “childs” ever be the plural of “child”?

Is the word "childs" ever used instead of children? And was it ever a part of standard English vocabulary but later neglected?
The answer to the first question is a simple no, suitable for ELL, but the answer to the second question requires some explication of Old English declensions, the merging of noun classes and their forms as Middle English developed from Old English, and the differentiation between northern and southern dialects of English. All of this is completely unsuitable for ELL

Comment: The question has now been reopened on ELU.

Comment: We got it back open on ELU, but Sven Yargs never reposted his answer, unfortunately :-(